# How to write to an array the output of an awk command in UNIX?

Tags: arrays, bash, unix, awk

I have a flat file which contains the following

```
INDIA USA SA NZ AUS ARG GER BRA
```

so there are eight columns altogether . Now I want to store the indexes of those columns only which starts with A into an array.
For that I tried the following statement

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^A/){set -A newArray $i}}}' testUnix.txt
```

when I echo the file using

```
echo "${newArray[*]}"
```

it's printing 5 6 but whenever I am trying to get the length of that array

```
echo ${#newArray[@]}
```

its length is being shown as 1 only. Should not it be 2 ?
I also tried

```
awk '{y = 0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^A/){newArray[y] = $i ; y++}}}' testUnix.txt
```

but also it's producing the same result.
What am I missing ?Please explain. I intend to get the desired output 2.

Comment: The `newArray` in awk and bash are two different entities. So when you type `echo "${newArray[*]}"` its the value of bash array you are getting

Comment: Have to say - I think this is where things like Perl or Python start to come into their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `awk`. You can loop through the elements and check if they start with `A`:

```
r="INDIA USA SA NZ AUS ARG GER BRA"
arr=()
for w in $r
do
    [[ $w == A* ]] && arr+=("$w")
done
```

If you execute it then the `arr` array contains:

```
$ for i in  "${arr[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
AUS
ARG
```

And to confirm that is has two elements, let's count them:

```
$ echo "${#arr[@]}"
2
```

---

What is happening with your aproach?

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^A/){set -A newArray $i}}}' testUnix.txt
```

this says `set -A newArray` but it is not really defining the variable in bash, because you are in awk.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do to have a bash array :

```
bash_arr=( $(awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^A/){print $i}}}' file) )
echo "${bash_arr[@]}"
AUS ARG
```

And you don't even need awk in reality, bash is capable of doing regex :

```
for word in $(<file); do [[ $word =~ ^A ]] && basharr+=( "$word" ); done
```

Comment: it's length is still 1 :(

Comment: ??? What's the problem ? You have the 2 searched elements. Dunno what's wrong. The index start @ zero !